# Can you passthrough a specific column in a scikit-learn ColumnTransformer?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a fairly large datframe(300 columns) and I'm using sklearn to encode/scale some fields, I like that I can choose the specific columns I want and then it drop the rest. My problem is, now I have two numpy arrays in two columns in my large data frame that I would like passed through while the others I don't list in the sklearn pipeline are dropped.

For example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer([("Country", OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder = 'passthrough')
```

This would convert the country to onehot and pass through everything. What if I have a column called "numpy_array" how can I get that one only passed through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What if I have a column called "numpy_array" how can I get that one only passed through?

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('np_array_transform', 'passthrough', ['numpy_array']),
    ],
    remainder='drop',
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't 100% understand this. I didn't know there was actually a passthrough option for specific columns. What is the first column mean?  'np_array_transform'?

Comment: @Lostsoul it's just an arbitrary name for the `numpy_array` transformer. Transformers in `ColumnTransformer` should be given in the form (name, scikit-learn transformer instance or 'drop' or 'passthrough', columns).